# Limpiar input con javascript en base a condición

Tags: javascript

Tengo el siguiente código en js que me realiza una validación para poder habilitar un input en base a una condición pero al momento de que sea mayor de edad necesito que realice lo siguiente que si existe algún texto en el input se ponga en blanco.

```
function ValidadEdad(RepPacVal, EdadVal) {

        // Accedemos al botón
        var RepresentanteValidacion = document.getElementById(RepPacVal);
        var EdadValidacion = $('#' + EdadVal).val(); // Obtenemos el Valor del campo Edad
        //console.log(EdadValidacion);
        if (EdadValidacion >= 18) { // Validamos si es mayor o menor
            // evento para el input Deshabilitado
            console.log("Mayor de edad");
            RepresentanteValidacion.disabled = true; // Deshabilitado
            document.getElementById(RepPacVal).textContent = ""; -- AQUI TRATO DE PONER EN BLANCO EL INPUT
        }
        else if (EdadValidacion < 18) {
            console.log("Menor de edad");
            // evento para el input Habilitar
            RepresentanteValidacion.disabled = false; // Habilitado
        }
```

}

Que estaría realizando erróneamente, agradezco sus comentarios y ayuda.

Comment: Una cuestión, te has asegurado de que la condición `if (EdadValidacion >= 18)` funcione? Te devuelve el `console.log("Mayor de edad")`. Si es así, la respuesta que te he adjuntado debería funcionarte

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posiblemente tu problema esté en `document.getElementById(RepPacVal).textContent = "";`..

Prueba en utilizar `.value` de esta forma :   `document.getElementById(RepPacVal).value = '';`

**NOTA**
`text.content()` devuelve el contenido dentro del input pero no lo modifica
`.value` modifica el contendio del input

Comment: Si esta modificación no te soluciona el problema escribe un comentario!

Comment: Entonces el `text.content` no es valido para realizar la modificación sino que siempre tengo que usar el `value`

Comment: `text.content` te devuelve el contenido pero no modifica el valor

Comment: Gracias campeón, un abrazo por la ayuda y la aclaración!

Comment: Encantado de ayudar y recibir ayuda ;) Un abrazo!